# how to get data correctly

Tags: php, loops

hello i'm going to get array data from for. i have a code but it works not good 
in the previous code cs=2

```
for($k=0;$k<$cs;$k++)
{ 


$SQL = "SELECT duration FROM core_network WHERE location=('".$location_c[$k]."')";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);


$cks="0";
$duration=array();
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$duration_c[$cks]= $db_field['duration']; //*here must save to data
 $cks++;

} 
 }
```

i have saved this code in the search_l.php

```
 <?php include("lib/search_l.php"); ?>



  <?php
if($cs!=0){
for($i=0;$i<$cs;$i++)
{ 

?>



 <div id="alarmdisplay">
   <table class width="634" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
  <tr class="search">
    <td width="256"><?php echo $location_c[$i] ?></td>
    <td width="154" class="247"><?php  echo $duration_c[$i]
?></td>
    <td width="194">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

in here it must be print 2 duration. but it prints only one others have error Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in how to print it by correct?

when i test it to check correct i noticed that:

```
$result)) {
$duration_c[$cks]= $db_field['duration'];
 $cks++;

} echo $duration_c[$cks]   //*it prints correct i meant prints 2 test data
}
```

after that

```
$result)) {
$duration_c[$cks]= $db_field['duration'];
 $cks++;

}  
}
echo $duration_c[$cks]  //*it prints not correct i meant prints only first test data
```

how to correct it?

Comment: You most likely want to loop through the array and echo each time you have a new result in the loop.

Comment: yes i want to get 2 data each corresponding cs but now i can get only one of them bt this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$duration_c=array();//Should be declared outside loop

for($k=0;$k<$cs;$k++)
 { 
  $SQL = "SELECT duration FROM core_network WHERE location=('".$location_c[$k]."')";
  $result = mysql_query($SQL);
  $cks = 0;//String variable
  while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                                                    //^---------returns associative array
      $duration_c[$cks]= $db_field['duration'];
      $cks++;
   } 
 }
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer but i can not solve still. i prints only last data in outside of for loop. in the inside it prints ok.

Comment: @Batnasanganpurev use var_dump($duration_c) outside of for loop to check values it should get values can you show me full code

Comment: hello i have found the error thanks for you your declare outside helps  me lot thanks

Comment: @Batnasanganpurev yup, you were declaring inside the for loop so everytime it was getting rewritten, declaring it outside will make it global..cheers n happy coding

Comment: hello if there are a duplicate Location how to choose one of them and how to know how many duplicated locations

Answer (score 0):

if you want a key types result (assoc array), use

```
mysql_fetch_assoc();
```

instead

```
mysql_fetch_array();
```

Comment: i have test it but there was same result. only difference was whan i use mysql_fetch_array();it prints first data,  down vote accept
 

if you want a key types result (assoc array), use

mysql_fetch_assoc(); it only prints second data

Answer (score 0):

Alright, then try something like this, this will get the results you inserted in the array.

```
<?php

for($i = 0; $i < count($duration); ++$i) {
    echo $duration[$i];
?>
```

Comment: i need to echo $duration outside of for loop. it is normal in inside but outside it prints only last data.

Answer (score 0):

there's a simple type error in your code:

```
$duration=array();
```

should be

```
$duration_c=array();
```

otherwise it will be a problem of scoping, because  `$duration_c` won't be know outside your `while` loop.